# D3 select multiple nodes or/and edges

Tags: select, d3.js

How can I select several nodes and edges in D3? I have implemented a D3 force-directed graph [here](http://jsfiddle.net/smallgoodboy/BJ934/). Now we can click a single node or edge to select it. Code:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
    var selectednode = d;
    //some ops
}
```

BUT How can I select more than one node at the same time, using mouse to draw a rectangle and select all the nodes within it?

Any answer is welcomed and an example is the best!

Comment: See e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/zrlram/2522963).